# Passing back Json data to back-side with KeyValuePair C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ienumerable, keyvaluepair

The thing I just want to do is to send back my JSON list to my POST method (EditCompanyReportField) that is in C# server side.Apparently, releated parameter (fieldSorted) on my method has array object, however values don't pass.I have couple of question marks

KeyValuePair is struct,not primitive type, because of that ?

Do I have to serialize JSON object ?

And I don't want to create a model class for it

back-side method

```
public void EditCompanyReportField(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> fieldSorted)
```

client-side JS

```
  var fieldSorted= [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.reportfield.length; i++) {
      fieldSorted.push({ Key: $scope.reportmapfield[i].MappedFieldId,
           Value: $scope.reportmapfield[i].IndexNo = i + 1 });   
      };


   $http({
            method: 'post', url: '/mapped/editcompanyreportfield',
            data: { fieldSorted: fieldSorted }
        }).success(function () {
            $state.go("list-report");
            toastr.success(infoMessage.success);
        });
```

fieldSorted parameter in back-side came out

```
   [0]  {[0,0]} 
   [1]  {[0,0]} 
   [2]  {[0,0]}
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code looks fine to me.

By default MVC is expecting the data to be passed as serialised form parameters which is not what you are doing. Have you set the content type of the AJAX request to "application/json"?

Comment: it is default for header, nevertheless I tried,no change.In fact, I want it to be feasable without doing something extra.Round-trip already works with plain model class well.I dont want to create a class for key/value only

Comment: Can you provide us with the Payload being sent to the server please?

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same problem, as I was trying to serialize back into a List< KeyValuePair< int, bool>> it resolved to

```
[0]  {[0,false]} 
[1]  {[0,false]} 
[2]  {[0,false]}
```

The workaround I used was to switch to Dictionary< int, bool >. Did not change anything with the data I was posting back in javascript and it started working.